# How to check if String contains Latin letters without regex

Tags: java

I want to check if String contains only Latin letters but also can contains numbers and other symbols like: _/+), etc.

String `utm_source=google` should pass, `utm_source=google&2019_and_2020!` should pass too. But `utm_ресурс=google` should not pass (coz cyrillic letters). I know code with regex, but how can i do it without using regex and classic for loop, maybe with Streams and Character class?

Comment: What does "other symbols" mean. Do you mean, symbols present on a QWERTY keyboard, or just, *every single other unicode character*

Comment: You have to be more specific of what exactly you want to exclude. Is the character NUL (`\0`) allowed? What about Emojis? What about `ä`? What about `ﬃ`?

Comment: Only Latin letters, numbers and standard symbols from QWERTY keyboard. `ä`, `ﬃ` not allowed.

Comment: Your definition is not as precise as you might think it is: What about `²`? That's on most keyboards I see. "standard symbols" simply has no precise meaning, you have to a. explicitly list every allowed symbol, or b.) specify an encoding that contains all allowed symbols (and none that are not allowed) or c.) reference some external definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code

```java
public static boolean isValidUsAscii (String s) {
        return Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder().canEncode(s);
}
```

Comment: The name does not match the implementation ISO Latin1 and US-ASCII are different encodings.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks, I fix the function naming. This code should work for you. I've tried this on both examples

Comment: @JoachimSauer still this could be intended, _latin_ (though not ISO) as in latin alphabet. Though Latin1 might be a too large set.

Comment: @JoopEggen: I disagree. *Either* they wanted US-ASCII to be the valid set or Latin1. Those two requirements are not compatible. Defining "latin" to mean "US-ASCII" is the kind of thinking that dragged us into this whole encoding mess in the first place: the world is not just English text (and even English *barely* fits into US-ASCII).

Answer (score 1):

For restricted "latin" (no é etcetera), it must be either US-ASCII (7 bits), or ISO-8859-1 but without accented letters.

```
boolean isBasicLatin(String s) {
    return s.codePoints().allMatch(cp -> cp < 128 || (cp < 256 && !isLetter(cp)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Less of a neat single line approach but really all you need to do is check whether the numeric value of the character is within certain limits like so:

```
public boolean isQwerty(String text) {
    int length = text.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char character = text.charAt(i);
        int ascii = character;
        if(ascii<32||ascii>126) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Test Run**

`ä` returns `false`

`abc` returns `true`